# Split two lines by zero in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file (named data) with many single files that they are separated by 0, I mean for example first line is data, and second line is zero, How can I split these file by re.split in python?

if between files is space, we use re.split('\n\s*\n', data), but when instead of space we have '0                  ', what is used?

Comment: So use `0` instead of `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `\s` to `0`. If there need to be one zero per line you can use `0`. If there might be many zeros - write `0+`. If zero or more - `0*`.

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: data = 'lorem ipsum\n0\ndorot sit'

In [3]: re.split('\n0+\n', data)
Out[3]: ['lorem ipsum', 'dorot sit']
```

Comment: Thank you so much sokoli for your try, but "\n0+\s*\n" works with my data.

Comment: So there are also some whitespace chars after 0 :)